# How to fetch hourly data for each day within two dates range in mysql?

Tags: mysql, sql

Below my query:

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT( FROM_UNIXTIME(  `temp_timing` ) ,  '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s' ) AS timing, temperature, deviceid
FROM tempdata
WHERE deviceid =29
AND DATE_FORMAT( FROM_UNIXTIME(  `temp_timing` ) ,  '%Y-%m-%d' ) >=  '2018-07-20'
AND DATE_FORMAT( FROM_UNIXTIME(  `temp_timing` ) ,  '%Y-%m-%d' ) <=  '2018-07-27'
ORDER BY timing ASC 
LIMIT 0 , 30
```

Comment: See: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: Instead of transforming `temp_timing` to a string and and compare the literal against it, you better use something like `temp_timing >= unix_timestamp('2018-07-20 00:00:00') AND temp_timing < unix_timestamp('2018-07-28 00:00:00')` -- perform the conversion on the literal rather than the column values. Like that indexes on `temp_timing` can still be used.

Comment: Thanks. Please tell me how can I get hourly based data for each day.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can be by the following query

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT( FROM_UNIXTIME(  `temp_timing` ) ,  '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s' ) AS timing, AVG( temperature ) AS avg, deviceid
FROM tempdata
WHERE deviceid =29
AND DATE_FORMAT( FROM_UNIXTIME(  `temp_timing` ) ,  '%Y-%m-%d' ) >=  '2018-07-20'
AND DATE_FORMAT( FROM_UNIXTIME(  `temp_timing` ) ,  '%Y-%m-%d' ) <=  '2018-07-27'
GROUP BY DATE( timing ) , HOUR( timing ) 
ORDER BY  `timing` ASC 
LIMIT 0 , 30
```

Comment: To group by with  n hours :-    SELECT DATE_FORMAT( FROM_UNIXTIME(  `temp_timing` ) ,  '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s' ) AS timing, AVG( temperature ) AS avg, deviceid
FROM tempdata
WHERE deviceid =29
AND DATE_FORMAT( FROM_UNIXTIME(  `temp_timing` ) ,  '%Y-%m-%d' ) >=  '2018-07-20'
AND DATE_FORMAT( FROM_UNIXTIME(  `temp_timing` ) ,  '%Y-%m-%d' ) <=  '2018-07-27'
GROUP BY DATE( timing ) , HOUR( timing ) DIV n
ORDER BY  `timing` ASC 
LIMIT 0 , 30